# Duplicate entry error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, duplicates

I am trying to save two models to the database.

USER and BOARD.

I do the following in the controller:

```
 if params_posted?(:user)
               @user = User.new(params[:user].merge :password => generate_random_string)
               @board = Board.new(params[:board])
               @spec =  Spec.new(:birthdate => params[:user][:deliver_on])
               @user.spec = @spec
               @pref = Pref.new
               @board.pref = @pref
if @board.save & @user.save
.
.
.
end
```

If the information is missing for the user the board still gets saved it seems. The form is shown with the correct error message asking the user to correct the missing or invalid information.

Now when the form is submitted again I get the following error:

```
mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '1000' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `boards
```

I don't want the record for the boards to be saved unless the user is saved. I have read about transactions and tried it but the record was still saved.

How can I stop this duplication from occuring?

Thank you in advance

Comment: show your form code and controller code. Looks like you are setting id to board manually

Comment: I'm not a Ruby-on-Rails programmer, but, generally speaking, can you not save the user, make sure that didn't fail (checking for errors or what have you) and then save the board?

Comment: Yes that was it fl00r. I ran code to compare the board being saved within so many seconds to trap for the form being submitted multiple times.  So I set the id to match the boards just saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have to save the user first, then the board object. And use `&&` operator which stands for logical AND.

```
if @user.save && @board.save
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. I just tried that but it still does the same thing. I need something like a transaction to make sure that both records are saved at the same time. Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: You can (a) add transaction block `User.transaction do ... end` or (b) check if both records are valid before saving them `if @user.valid? && @board.valid? ...`. But remember to rollback the transaction if one record isn't saved or use `save!` method which throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks Greg I will get on that and see what happens. I appreciate your suggestions.